# Ajax validation is doing partially validation in Yii

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I want to validate my form with Ajax Validation method.So for I have made changes the code for view file like this.

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'customers-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'focus'=>array($model,'firstname,lastname,gender,email,contact_no,address,state,country'),
)); ?>

  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstname'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>80)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastname'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'gender',array('Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female'),array(
      'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline;padding-right:10px'),'separator'=>'',));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'contact_no'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contact_no',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'contact_no'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'address'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'address',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>120)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'address'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'state',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'state'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'country'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'country',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'country'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
  </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I have made the rules for this model is like this

```
 public function rules()
  {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
      array('firstname,lastname,gender,email,contact_no,address,state,country', 'required'),
      array('firstname, lastname', 'length', 'max'=>80),
    );
  }
```

After all this code I came to see that all the fields are showing validation in a normal way but when going through Ajax Validation the only  `Firstname, Lastname, Email` is showing ajax validation.Rest of the fields are not showing any ajax validation.Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong here?Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciable.
**Edited**
Here is the code for controller which is handling the Ajax validation

```
  protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='customers-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you show the controller code that is handling this form?

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev for your quick reply.I have made updated the code for controller.

Comment: Thanks @bool.dev for trying to solve this problem.I have got the solution.

Comment: ok, great, i was puzzled as to what is wrong, all the code in the question was correct, except i would say that the `focus` property of the form, should be used only for the field that you want to have focus, when the form first loads.

Comment: I think you are missing safe validation rule.
please apply "safe" validation for all the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this in model's actionCreate()

```
 public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Customers;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Customers']))
    {
      if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
      {
        echo CActiveForm::validate( array( $model)); 
        Yii::app()->end(); 
      }
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Customers'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      if($valid)
      {
        $model->save();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }
```

Rest of the files for view will be the same as above made in question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried, you can follow this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new Main;

if(isset($_POST['ajax']) )
{
echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
Yii::app()->end();
}
if(isset($_POST['Main']))
```

In the view:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'main-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),))
```

'true is needed'